# How to get part of a string when the string can be different each time

Tags: php, string, substring

So I have a string that is retrieved from my database. The returned value could be laid out like

```
VD-6||CL-4
```

or just

```
VD-6
```

I need the value after the hyphen. so for instance if it returned

```
VD-12||CL-5
```

I need to extract "12" from that string.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what to try. I assume I can use Regex but I do not know it very well and can't figure out a pattern.  if it was always the same format I could had used substr but I don't think that is going to work in this case.

Comment: `echo preg_match("/[0-9]+/", $string, $matches[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using Regular Expressions, or just the old fashion splitting method.

Let me give you an example on the second one:

```
$string = 'VD-12||CL-5';

$split = explode('-', $string);
$yourNumber = intval($split[1]); // $yourNumber = 12
```

But.... I would prefer fixing this with regular expressions. But it's really hard to give a concrete example of a regular expression without exactly knowing the requirements for the regex and the input.
Same goes for my code example above, by the way. But I just went with the information you provided.

Comment: It will always have a format of  either   VD-##   or  VD-## || CL-##

Comment: Regex isn't hard: `echo preg_match("/[0-9]+/", $string, $matches[0]);`

Comment: In that case I would go with the example of @Daan

Answer (score -1):

```
// get 12 out of VD-12||CL-5
// or get 6 out of VD-6

$string = "VD-12||CL-5";

//$string = "VD-6";

$strpos = strpos($string, '|');

if($strpos){
echo substr($string, strpos($string, '-') +1, $strpos-3);
}else{
echo substr($string, strpos($string, '-') +1);

}
```

But a bit mor information could be useful

[demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3231d3d991e7c93c14e254c534290f49bd1d67ef)